# Custom navigation bar not showing

Tags: ios, navigationbar

Controller 1 displays an array of `UIImages`, Controller 2 manages the paging of those images once selected, and Controller 3 just displays the images for the pages. When I tap on a cell and load a photo into the `photoViewController`, the paging of images works fine, but my custom navigation bar is overridden with the default bar and I am unable to add any custom buttons to it or change any of its properties in code. The only thing I found that I am able to do is hide it. If I try to change the title of the back button or add my own title to the navigation bar nothing changes. Please help with anything you can.

[image]

Comment: Why you have 2 navigation controller? or you mean you have extended the navigation bar class with yours

Comment: I was following the example here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084002/correct-way-to-transition-between-collection-view-and-paged-detail-view

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try like this

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [self leftMenuBarButtonItem];
```

and function could be

```
    - (UIBarButtonItem *)leftMenuBarButtonItem {

    UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 30)];    [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_btn_bg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(leftDrawerButtonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
}
```

if you fall in between let me know

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code but didn't get any different results. In my viewDidLoad for my PhotoViewController (controller 3) if I code 
`self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;` the navigation bar is hidden. But if I try to say: `self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"Back";` I get the default back boomerang icon with previous controllers title as my back button.

Comment: do not set the back button tile as it will not work, create the custom UIButton and then use is as bar button and you will see the customisation